# Barplot of mean values of different groups in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data set of stock portfolios including their trade history. My data set `df` is similar to the following example:

```
pf_id   trade_day   price  buy inital_trade
1001    01.09.14    14.22   1   1
1001    04.09.14    52.33   1   0
1001    08.09.14    47.33   0   0
1001    12.09.14    53.12   1   0
1001    15.09.14    112.13  0   0
...             
1791    02.02.15    10.23   1   1
1791    07.02.15    37.88   1   0
1791    13.02.15    23.32   1   0
1791    17.02.15    54.34   1   0
1791    23.02.15    27.44   0   0
...             
2232    20.10.14    38.12   1   1
2232    21.10.14    34.45   1   0
2232    23.10.14    35.78   1   0
2232    01.11.14    39.98   0   0
2232    11.11.14    44.23   0   0
2232    21.11.14    111.23  0   0
2232    23.11.14    324.56  1   0
2232    04.12.14    145.56  0   0
2232    07.12.14    45.67   1   0
...
```

where `pf_id` is the ID of the corresponding portfolio, `trade_day` is the date of the transaction, `price` is the trading price, `buy` is a dummy indicating whether the stocks were bought or sold, and `initial_trade` is a dummy indicating the first trade of a new portfolio.

I want to plot the trading activity over the lifetime across all portfolios with the months on the x-axis and the mean number of trades across all portfolios on the y-axis. So far I can get the plot only for one specific portfolio, e.g.,

```
df$month <- as.Date(cut(df$trade_day, breaks="month"))     
ggplot(df[df$id==1001],aes(month) + geom_bar()
```

But I like to have the mean trading activity across all portfolios, i.e, the mean number of trades in the first month of all portfolios, for the second months and so on. Moreover, I want to do the same for the trading volume (mean buy volume in the first month, mean sell volume in the first month, ...).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you be more specific about what you would like to see on the y-axis of this plot? mean buy by month? mean initial_trade by month? etc.

Comment: if you want a barplot, you will need to summarise your dataset by pf_id first.

Comment: @bjoseph: I added the axes to the question

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that requires `dplyr`.

First, I convert your dates to the `Date` data type, and then create a variable `month` that contains the month of the trade.

`df=df%>%mutate(trade_date=as.Date(df$trade_day,"%d.%m.%y"))%>%
  mutate(month=format(trade_date, "%m")`

Next, I count the trades by month and the total rows per month by `pf_id`, then I make an average of these.

`plot = df%>%group_by(month,pf_id)%>%summarize(trades=sum(inital_trade),n=n())%>%
  group_by(month)%>%summarize(average=trades/n)%>%mutate(month=as.factor(month))`

Then I create a bar plot of the output.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)


df=read.csv("~/Documents/stackoverflow.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df=df%>%mutate(trade_date=as.Date(df$trade_day,"%d.%m.%y"))%>%
  mutate(month=format(trade_date, "%m"))


plot = df%>%group_by(month,pf_id)%>%summarize(trades=sum(inital_trade),n=n())%>%
  group_by(month)%>%summarize(average=trades/n)%>%mutate(month=as.factor(month))


ggplot(plot,aes(x=month,y=average)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')]
```

[image]    [![

Comment: you use whitespace when typing words but not code? weird

Comment: do you mean in the text of the answer? i tried to make it more readable, i'm happy to implement any suggestions you have.

Comment: @rawr to be fair, there are two spaces and several end line characters. He is being sarcastic because you're not using any "pretty" formatting in your code, making it for the rest of us arguably less readable.

Comment: @bjoseph: Many thanks for your solution. As the pfs exist for more than one year, the mean of Feb. would be the mean in Feb. across all years? (e.g., if one pf trades in Feb. 2014 and Feb. 2015, the graph plots the mean across both years). What I am looking for is: on the x-axis: 1st month the pfs exist, 2nd month the pfs exist and so on. On the y-axis should be the mean number of trades for each month (in the example this would be: 13/3 for the first month, 4/3 for the second,..). E.g., the first month is not the same for all pfs, because it depends on when the pf was opened.

Comment: In that case you should change the `group_by` variables accordingly. You'd have to probably create a `pf_lag` (or whatever) variable as well.